# remove duplicate character from string in pure bash - works in CLI but does not work in script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, regex, string

I want to remove all duplicate minuses from a string using pure bash (no sed/awk/etc). This works great in CLI:

```
s="com---strig-3-1080p-----mp4"
echo "${s//+(-)/-}"

com-strig-3-1080p-mp4  # output
```

When I do the same in a script, it does not work:

```
cat sanitize.sh

#!/bin/bash
s="${1?need a string}"
echo "1 $s"  # debug output

s="${s//+(-)/-}"             # convert multiple - to single -
echo "2 $s"  # debug output
```

Now test:

```
sanitize.sh "com---strig-3-1080p-----mp4"
1 com---strig-3-1080p-----mp4
2 com---strig-3-1080p-----mp4
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The availability of `+(...)` in Bash generally depends on whether the `extglob` shell option is enabled. There are some exceptions, e.g. the right-hand side of `[[` string comparisons can always use extglobs, but `${x/y/z}` string substitutions are not one of those exceptions. You need to enable the option using:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

You'll need to do this near the top of your script. (Since shell scripts run in their own processes separate from your interactive shell, they all have their own sets of "enabled options" and cannot inherit them from the interactive shell… and it would make things function very inconsistently if they did.)